# How to debug Postgres copy command failure

Tags: postgresql, sqlbulkcopy, postgresql-8.4

I have around 75k records which I am loading to a Postgres table using copy command which is failing. I get an exception

> ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xbd

Now i need to find which line is having this entry. Is there any way to do this? I am thinking in lines of enabling some postgres logging that might help or any other solution
Note: I am getting the issue with only one particular file. Other files are getting loaded without issues

Answer (score 1):

I always seem to get a line-number in my error, no matter whether I use `COPY` or `\copy` and feed a file via redirection or `-f`.

```
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xa3
CONTEXT:  COPY z, line 3
```

If there are only a couple of bad chars and you just want to strip them you can use iconv (assuming you're on a unix-like system).

```
iconv -c --from=utf8 --to=utf8 /tmp/badchars.txt > /tmp/stripped.txt
```

You could always run diff against the before + after versions if you wanted to see what was stripped out.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I will try iconv. But I am not seeing the line number. Is it enabled by -f or by enabling some logging params?

Comment: @rajesh You're probably using an old version of PostgreSQL. You didn't say in your question.